# gcc: Permission denied while compiling Makefile as root

Tags: gcc, makefile, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to install [ndiswrapper](https://sourceforge.net/p/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper/Main_Page/) in Ubuntu 22.04.

The instructions in the INSTALL file say:

```
Download the latest version of the ndiswrapper sources from here and
extract it with the command

  tar zxvf ndiswrapper-version.tar.gz

This will create ndiswrapper-version directory. Change to that
directory and run

  make uninstall
  make

Login as root and run
  make install
```

I did this exactly (replacing "version" with "1.63").  I received permission errors with `make uninstall` so I instead ran `sudo make uninstall`  with success.  Then I ran `sudo make` and received the following output:

```
make -C utils
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/laura/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63/utils'
gcc -g -Wall -I../driver  -o loadndisdriver loadndisdriver.c
make[1]: gcc: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [Makefile:16: loadndisdriver] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/laura/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63/utils'
make: *** [Makefile:23: utils] Error 2
```

Another article suggested that the path to gcc may need to be specified, so I went in ndiswrapper-1.63/utils/Makefile and changed `CC=gcc` to `CC=/usr/bin/gcc`.  Now the output is:

```
sudo make
make -C utils
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/laura/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63/utils'
/usr/bin/gcc -g -Wall -I../driver  -o loadndisdriver loadndisdriver.c
make[1]: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [Makefile:16: loadndisdriver] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/laura/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63/utils'
make: *** [Makefile:23: utils] Error 2
```

I investigated gcc.

```
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ gcc --version
Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gcc
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ which gcc
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep gcc
c89-gcc
c99-gcc
gcc
gcc-11
gcc-ar
gcc-ar-11
gcc-nm
gcc-nm-11
gcc-ranlib
gcc-ranlib-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-11
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls -ld /usr/*bin /usr/*bin/gcc*
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 49152 Dec 12 15:31 /usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Dec  7 10:25 /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    23 Apr 30  2022 /usr/bin/gcc-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Aug  5  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    26 Apr 30  2022 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Aug  5  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    26 Apr 30  2022 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    13 Aug  5  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    30 Apr 30  2022 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-11
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 20480 Dec 11 17:05 /usr/sbin
```

Another article suggested that I may have more than one installation of gcc/directory called gcc.  I found a deb file in my home directory and removed it.

```
laura@orion:~$ ls -s | grep gcc
19628 gcc-11_11.3.0-1ubuntu1_22.04_amd64.deb
laura@orion:~$ rm gcc-11_11.3.0-1ubuntu1_22.04_amd64.deb
```

The empty output of `which gcc` is disturbing and suggests it might not be installed correctly, so I tried removing and reinstalling both it and `make` using `sudo apt-get remove make gcc` and `sudo apt-get install make gcc`.  Both problems persist.

I found that somebody else solved their problem by specifying the version of gcc at install.

```
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
11
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-11
```

Successful reinstall, but both problems persist.

I tried to more aggressively force remove all installation of gcc.

```
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep gcc
c89-gcc
c99-gcc
gcc
gcc-11
gcc-ar
gcc-ar-11
gcc-nm
gcc-nm-11
gcc-ranlib
gcc-ranlib-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-11
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt purge gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debugedit dh-autoreconf
  dh-strip-nondeterminism dwz g++-11 gcc-11 gettext intltool-debian
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasan6 libb-hooks-op-check-perl
  libcc1-0 libdebhelper-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdpkg-perl
  libdynaloader-functions-perl libegl-dev libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
  libgles-dev libgles1 libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev
  libglx-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libltdl-dev libmail-sendmail-perl
  libmodule-pluggable-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libopengl-dev
  libparams-classify-perl libpthread-stubs0-dev libquadmath0 libsigsegv2
  libstdc++-11-dev libsub-override-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libtool
  libtsan0 libubsan1 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev
  libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  lto-disabled-list m4 po-debconf wx-common wx3.0-headers x11proto-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gcc*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 51.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 211994 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gcc (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing gcc, directory '/usr/bin/gcc' not empty so not rem
oved
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt-get purge gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gcc' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debugedit dh-autoreconf
  dh-strip-nondeterminism dwz g++-11 gcc-11 gettext intltool-debian
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasan6 libb-hooks-op-check-perl
  libcc1-0 libdebhelper-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdpkg-perl
  libdynaloader-functions-perl libegl-dev libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
  libgles-dev libgles1 libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev
  libglx-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libltdl-dev libmail-sendmail-perl
  libmodule-pluggable-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libopengl-dev
  libparams-classify-perl libpthread-stubs0-dev libquadmath0 libsigsegv2
  libstdc++-11-dev libsub-override-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libtool
  libtsan0 libubsan1 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev
  libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  lto-disabled-list m4 po-debconf wx-common wx3.0-headers x11proto-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt-get purge gcc-11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debugedit dh-strip-nondeterminism
  dwz gettext intltool-debian libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasan6
  libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcc1-0 libdebhelper-perl
  libdevel-callchecker-perl libdpkg-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl
  libegl-dev libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl
  libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1
  libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libitm1 liblsan0
  libltdl-dev libmail-sendmail-perl libmodule-pluggable-perl
  libmodule-runtime-perl libopengl-dev libparams-classify-perl
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libquadmath0 libsigsegv2 libstdc++-11-dev
  libsub-override-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libtsan0 libubsan1
  libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev
  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev lto-disabled-list m4
  po-debconf wx-common wx3.0-headers x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dh-autoreconf* g++-11* gcc-11* libtool*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 84.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 211958 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing dh-autoreconf (20) ...
Removing g++-11 (11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Removing libtool (2.4.6-15build2) ...
Removing gcc-11 (11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt-get purge gcc-ar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-ar
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt purge gcc-11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gcc-11' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debugedit dh-strip-nondeterminism
  dwz gettext intltool-debian libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasan6
  libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcc1-0 libdebhelper-perl
  libdevel-callchecker-perl libdpkg-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl
  libegl-dev libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl
  libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1
  libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libitm1 liblsan0
  libltdl-dev libmail-sendmail-perl libmodule-pluggable-perl
  libmodule-runtime-perl libopengl-dev libparams-classify-perl
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libquadmath0 libsigsegv2 libstdc++-11-dev
  libsub-override-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libtsan0 libubsan1
  libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev
  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev lto-disabled-list m4
  po-debconf wx-common wx3.0-headers x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt purge gcc-ar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-ar
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep gcc
gcc
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls /usr/lib/ | grep gcc
gcc
```

```
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep gcc
c89-gcc
c99-gcc
gcc
gcc-11
gcc-ar
gcc-ar-11
gcc-nm
gcc-nm-11
gcc-ranlib
gcc-ranlib-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-11
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-11
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt purge gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debugedit dh-autoreconf
  dh-strip-nondeterminism dwz g++-11 gcc-11 gettext intltool-debian
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasan6 libb-hooks-op-check-perl
  libcc1-0 libdebhelper-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdpkg-perl
  libdynaloader-functions-perl libegl-dev libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
  libgles-dev libgles1 libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev
  libglx-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libltdl-dev libmail-sendmail-perl
  libmodule-pluggable-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libopengl-dev
  libparams-classify-perl libpthread-stubs0-dev libquadmath0 libsigsegv2
  libstdc++-11-dev libsub-override-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libtool
  libtsan0 libubsan1 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev
  libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  lto-disabled-list m4 po-debconf wx-common wx3.0-headers x11proto-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gcc*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 51.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 211994 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gcc (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing gcc, directory '/usr/bin/gcc' not empty so not rem
oved
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt-get purge gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gcc' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debugedit dh-autoreconf
  dh-strip-nondeterminism dwz g++-11 gcc-11 gettext intltool-debian
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasan6 libb-hooks-op-check-perl
  libcc1-0 libdebhelper-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdpkg-perl
  libdynaloader-functions-perl libegl-dev libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
  libgles-dev libgles1 libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev
  libglx-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libltdl-dev libmail-sendmail-perl
  libmodule-pluggable-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libopengl-dev
  libparams-classify-perl libpthread-stubs0-dev libquadmath0 libsigsegv2
  libstdc++-11-dev libsub-override-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libtool
  libtsan0 libubsan1 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev
  libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  lto-disabled-list m4 po-debconf wx-common wx3.0-headers x11proto-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt-get purge gcc-11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debugedit dh-strip-nondeterminism
  dwz gettext intltool-debian libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasan6
  libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcc1-0 libdebhelper-perl
  libdevel-callchecker-perl libdpkg-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl
  libegl-dev libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl
  libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1
  libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libitm1 liblsan0
  libltdl-dev libmail-sendmail-perl libmodule-pluggable-perl
  libmodule-runtime-perl libopengl-dev libparams-classify-perl
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libquadmath0 libsigsegv2 libstdc++-11-dev
  libsub-override-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libtsan0 libubsan1
  libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev
  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev lto-disabled-list m4
  po-debconf wx-common wx3.0-headers x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dh-autoreconf* g++-11* gcc-11* libtool*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 84.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 211958 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing dh-autoreconf (20) ...
Removing g++-11 (11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Removing libtool (2.4.6-15build2) ...
Removing gcc-11 (11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt-get purge gcc-ar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-ar
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt purge gcc-11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gcc-11' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debugedit dh-strip-nondeterminism
  dwz gettext intltool-debian libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasan6
  libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcc1-0 libdebhelper-perl
  libdevel-callchecker-perl libdpkg-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl
  libegl-dev libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl
  libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1
  libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libitm1 liblsan0
  libltdl-dev libmail-sendmail-perl libmodule-pluggable-perl
  libmodule-runtime-perl libopengl-dev libparams-classify-perl
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libquadmath0 libsigsegv2 libstdc++-11-dev
  libsub-override-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libtsan0 libubsan1
  libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev
  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev lto-disabled-list m4
  po-debconf wx-common wx3.0-headers x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ sudo apt purge gcc-ar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-ar
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep gcc
gcc
laura@orion:~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.63$ ls /usr/lib/ | grep gcc
gcc
```

Please excuse my ignorance, I didn't know if there was a difference between apt and apt-get (my impression is they are different repositories) or between gcc and gcc-11 and gcc-ar, so I tried to be thorough.
Then I installed again with `sudo apt install gcc`.

Both problems still persist: `which gcc` returns nothing, `gcc --version` returns "command not found", and `sudo make` returns `make[1]: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied`.

Please help.

Comment: my guess - the file is in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very very wrong:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Dec  7 10:25 /usr/bin/gcc
```

The *d* at the beginning here says that this is a directory, which is definitely wrong.  It should be a file or a symlink to a file (in fact, your compiler).  This is what all the warnings like this are about:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing gcc, directory '/usr/bin/gcc' not empty so not removed
```

The date suggests that somehow on Dec 7 you created a directory for `gcc` (it's HIGHLY unlikely that any of the standard Linux tools such as `apt` did such a thing).

You should uninstall gcc, then remove the directory, then re-install it:

```
sudo apt remove gcc
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/gcc
sudo apt install gcc
```

Now your `which gcc` should show you `/usr/bin/gcc`.  Technically `type gcc` is better than `which` but either will work here.

Also just to note: you should definitely *not* run `sudo make`.  You may need `sudo` to uninstall and install the software but you definitely should not need it to build the software.

Comment: This was immensely helpful!  I think I did create that gcc directory when I was trying to install packages by USB before I had an ethernet connection (an extremely painful process).  
  
What would apt use instead of a directory?  A link?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand the question...?

Comment: You said that `apt` would never create a directory for `gcc`.  What would `apt` do instead?
(This isn't important, I'm just asking out of curiosity.)

Comment: Things created in `bin` directories are programs to be invoked (or links to programs to be invoked).  They are not subdirectories.  Obviously every package installs a different set of files and whatever the package wants to be installed, that's what `apt` will do.  But a package would never create a directory  named `/usr/bin/gcc`.